# How to display a QWidget in Ubuntu Touch using QML and C++?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, c++, qml

How can I display text from QTextEdit (a QWidget) using a QML frontend and a C++ backend? I am currently developing a Ubuntu Phone app using the qmake project. I need advanced text editing capabilities that the QML TextEdit cannot offer. I want to use QTextEdit but I cannot get it to display any text.

In the future, I will pass text into the QTextEdit object to display the text in a special format.

In this example, "Hello World" should be displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Screenshot:
[image: QTextEdit]

Here is my current code:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import TextEdit 1.0
/*!
    \brief MainView with a Label and Button elements.
*/

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "textedit.username"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    //automaticOrientation: true

    // Removes the old toolbar and enables new features of the new header.
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("textEdit")
        MyEditor {
            // should display Hello World by default (defined in C++)
        }
    }
}
```

myeditor.h

```
#ifndef MYEDITOR
#define MYEDITOR

#include <QtGui>
#include <QTextEdit>


class MyEditor : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyEditor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyEditor();


};

#endif // MYEDITOR
```

myeditor.cpp

```
#include "myeditor.h"

MyEditor::MyEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QTextEdit(parent)
{
    this->setHtml("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}

MyEditor::~MyEditor() {

}
```

backend.cpp

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>
#include "backend.h"
#include "mytype.h"
#include "myeditor.h"


void BackendPlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri)
{
    Q_ASSERT(uri == QLatin1String("TextEdit"));

    qmlRegisterType<MyType>(uri, 1, 0, "MyType");
    qmlRegisterType<MyEditor>(uri, 1, 0, "MyEditor");
}

void BackendPlugin::initializeEngine(QQmlEngine *engine, const char *uri)
{
    QQmlExtensionPlugin::initializeEngine(engine, uri);
}
```

Finally, I added "widgets" to the following line the the pro file:

```
QT += qml quick widgets
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it should work that early in the constructor...

Comment: I can set the "html" property in qml and it still has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it's actually from the the Qt Widgets. Qt Widgets can't be easily pasted into QML user interface.

There were some similar questions on StackOverflow: [qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml)

Comment: I read the Stack Overflow link that you provided. Is there a way to incorporate the QWidget::createWindowContainer? I tried this method ([link](http://www.ics.com/blog/combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer)) and it created a second window.